# How to fetch results from a PDO prepare statement

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I am using a PDO prepare statement to select the result.

My *index.php* file is:

```
include('operations.php');

$userprofileobj = new operations();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_email']))
{
    $results = $userprofileobj->verify_user('account', $_SESSION['user_email'])->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo $results['username'];
}
```

My *operations.php* file is:

```
<?php
    include('userclass.php');

    class operations extends userclass
    {
        public function verify_user($table_name, $user_email)
        {
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("select * from " . $table_name . " where username = :user_email");

            $stmt->execute([
                ':user_email' => $user_email,
            ]);

            return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to match email and the result should be fetched in *index.php*. But I got an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on boolean in operations.php on line 84

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `result` variable (besides being overwritten) is not what you think it is. It's a PDO statement.

Try this instead:

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("select * from ".$table_name." where username = :user_email");

$stmt->execute([
    ':user_email' => $user_email,
]);

if (false !== ($row = $stmt->fetchColumn()))
{
    return $row;
}
```

However, this will only return the first column of the first row.  Instead you probably want:

```
 return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I changed `$result` to `$stmt`, because it's not a result. It's a Statement Object.

**Original issues**

In your *original* code (see below) you are overwriting it with the return from `execute` which is a Boolean.

```
// Old code (don't use this)
$result = $result->execute([
    ':user_email' => $user_email,
]);

//$result = TRUE|FALSE

if ($result->fetchColumn() !== false)
{
    return $result;
}
```

And then you try to call a method of the Boolean, which, well, won't work.  But the problems are deeper than just that. Let’s assume you don’t overwrite it.

```
// Old code (don't use this)
$result->execute([
    ':user_email' => $user_email,
]);

//$result = PDOStatment object.

if ($result->fetchColumn() !== false)
{
    return $result;
}
```

Now the result is still your PDOStatement, which is good, but as I said, you're not saving the fetched data.  This time you return the PDOStatement object.  Which is not what you want.

Then further, as I stated earlier, if you do save it and return it, it's still probably not what you are after.  Because `fetchColumn()` accesses only one row at a time and only one column.

But I have no way to know what you want.  Maybe that is what you want?  In that case your query is less than *ideal*.  Maybe you just want to see if a user exists with a given email?  In that case I would use this query.

```
$result = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM ".$table_name." WHERE username = :user_email");

$result->execute([
    ':user_email' => $user_email,
]);
// There isn't any need to check it (see below)
return $result->fetchColumn();
```

> PDOStatement::fetchColumn() returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows.

I can also tell by your stuff, that your database setup is probably wrong. That is, if you really need a dynamic table `$table`.  The reason I can say this is you should not be duplicating any user data (or any data really, this is called normalization), and having the table dynamic implies that the email may exist separately in two (or more) tables.

If that is not the case then don't make it dynamic. Why is this an issue? Well, think what happens if a user changes their "email" now, because it exists in two tables (potentially). You'll have to update it in both places.  But it's worse than that as it overcomplicates anything you do with the emails.

Without seeing the schema for your tables, I can only speculate on that, and how to fix it.  But generally you would use a foreign key and associate the user record to that. Then using a JOIN you can access the email without duplication.

That said, there are a few cases where this may be acceptable, but I have no way to know if that is true in your case.  Just a quick example would be a separate table for users and administrators (basically two-user systems).

**Security**

The last thing is be very very careful with this:

```
"select * from ".$table_name." where username = :user_email"
```

The issue here is it's open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Anytime you concatenate a variable into SQL, you open the door for *injection* attacks.  Well, you may say I'm passing in a canned string `account`.  Which is OK, but there is no validation at the *point of failure*.  So maybe in five months you reuse this code and forget that you never validated the table name.  Maybe not, but the fact remains that if user data could get into that argument, you have no protection whatsoever against *injection* on the table name. The possibility for it is there.

Something as simple as this:

```
  public function verify_user($table_name,$user_email){
     $allowed = ['account','users'];
     if(!in_array($table_name, $allowed )) throw new Exception('Invalid table name');
 }
```

See now it's virtually impossible to *inject* something into the table name.  Further because it's in the same method (at the point of failure), you will never lose that protection.  It's very easy to be in a rush latter and copy a piece of code change a few things and .... well you know.

Just my two cents.

**UPDATE**

So even if the chance is small that user input could get into `$table` you can not guarantee it 100%, because from within `verify_user` you have no way to know where the data came from, but you are trusting on faith that it's not user input.  When it comes to SQL injection, you can't say well this is OK, because I will only call this method a certain way.  It has to be 100% injection proof or as close as is humanly possible.

Why is this important, you ask?  Imagine this.

```
   $userprofileobj->verify_user('account --',$_SESSION['user_email']);
```

Those two little `--`s are like `//` in PHP, but for SQL, they comment out the rest of the line in SQL so your query becomes this.

```
"select * from account -- where username = :user_email"
```

Or (essentially)

```
"select * from account"
```

So we just modified what your query does.  Now thankfully it's not really possible to run two queries at once in PDO. You can do it (with some work) in MySqli.  But because of security reasons, they have mostly done away with this ability.  The reason is this (or worse like creating database users).

```
  $userprofileobj->verify_user('account; DROP TABLE account --',$_SESSION['user_email']);
```

Which, if you could do two queries, would do this:

```
 SELECT * FROM account
 DROP TABLE account
```

In any case this is dangerous stuff and is to be avoided at all costs.  Being too lazy (and I am a *lazy* programmer, so don't take that wrong) to put a table name in is not an answer you want to give after your database has been compromised and you have exposed user data to a third party.  It's just not an option.

All this does:

```
if(!in_array($table_name, ['table1', 'table2', ...])) throw new Exception('Invalid table name');
```

Is throw an error if "needle" `$table_name` is not in "haystack" - a canned list of table names.  So if I do this (using our example above):

```
if(!in_array('account --', ['table1', 'table2', ...])) throw new Exception('Invalid table name');
```

It won't find `account --` in our list of `table1` and `table2` and will blow up, thus preventing the injection attack.

Comment: Thank you for reply and suggestion. But it is also not working. Where is the problem now?

Comment: `But it is also not working. Where is the problem now`  How should I know.  What's not working specifically.  I have no idea  what your DB looks like, what you are searching on etc...

Comment: I am trying to get row from my query and I have change my operation.php

Comment: OK. Now I understand...Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure, I hope all that made sense, because there were a lot of little mistakes.

Comment: One more thing...about your security help..public function verify_user($table_name,$user_email){
     $allowed = ['account','users'];
     if(!in_array($table_name, $allowed )) throw new Exception('Invalid table name');
 }

Comment: What about it, specifically?

Comment: In your code. If I have 3 tables. ACCOUNT, PRODUCTS, CONTACTS...then I have to write all tables in $allowed = ['ACCOUNT','PRODUCTS','CONTACTS'];

Comment: Yes, you can also do it like this `if(!in_array($table_name, ['ACCOUNT','PRODUCTS','CONTACTS'])) throw new Exception('Invalid table name');`  all on one line.  Without that, I'll put an example in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $this->con->prepare("select * from ".$table_name." where username = :user_email");

$result = $result->execute(..)
```

You're overwriting $result.  The $this->con->prepare(..) sets $result to be a PDO Statement (See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).  A PDO Statement object has the method ->execute(...), which returns a boolean (true/false) as well as the ->fetchColumn() method.  When you're doing your execute() you're overwriting your PDO Statement Object with the result of the execute() which is only a boolean and has no  methods in it at all.  As such that's why $result has no ->fetchColumn() method.

Comment: it's of no consequence

Comment: Thankyou for ur reply..but what is the solution.

Comment: Easiest thing is to make $result = $result->execute(..) into just $result->execute(..), however @ArtisticPhoenix goes into more detail in their answer.

Comment: It's not the easiest thing.  It's but one of the things that need to be done.  Changing that does not change the fact that they return `$result` which is not the "result" of the fetch* operation.  In other words, fixing that would return the Statement object after the pointer is moved past the first row, and you can't rewind the cursor for PDO.  Further, using `fetchColumn` when the query has no limit and pulls all the fields, means either the query is not optimal or they are using the wrong fetch method.